# How to stop normalizePath from returning a tokenized path

Tags: r, text, runtime-error, token, output

I have an R program that does a bunch of data analysis and outputs the results to a text file. Unfortunately when I call

```
system2("open", file_path_as_absolute(toFile));
```

The R interpreter states the following

```
'../output/HLA-A,B,C,DR,DP,DQ' not found
'GT2' not found
'vs' not found
'LT2_DRB1_output2of9.10.11.12.13.14.16.25.26.28.30.31.32.33.37.38.40.47.57.58.60
.67.70.71.73.74.77.78.85.86.txt' not found
```

I am assuming, based upon this error, that the file_path_as_absolute tokenizes the file name, but I am not sure how to disable this. I have also tried normalizePath(), but I get the same error.

**Edit**

The file itself is called

```
"HLA-A,B,C,DR,DP,DQ GT2 vs LT2_DRB1_output2of9.10.11.12.13.14.16.25.26.28.30.31.32.33.37.38.40.47.57.58.60.67.70.71.73.74.77.78.85.86.txt"
```

and is located in `../output`

Here is the code I ran to open the file, which gave me the same error

```
openSesame <- paste0('"', file_path_as_absolute(toFile), '"');
system2("open", openSesame);
```

Comment: the help file says that `file_path_as_absolute` is a wrapper for `normalizePath`, so it's not surprising that you get the same answer.  Reproducible example please: what is `toFile`?  Does it have spaces in it (generally a bad idea)?  If so you may need to protect it with quotes ...  It looks like the errors are from the OS (i.e. from `open`), not the R interpreter ...

Comment: PS did you examine the results of `file_path_as_absolute(toFile)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker toFile is the variable which holds the name of the file I want to open. How do I protect it with quotes? The output file does have spaces in its name.

Comment: probably `paste0('"',file_path_as_absolute(toFile)),'"')` will work.  But a reproducible example http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 would be very helpful.

Comment: This does not work, I will show you the updated code on my original post

Comment: OK, I should have said *should* work or *might* work ... look forward to your edits showing the value of `toFile` and `file_path_as_absolute(toFile)` from your session ...

Answer (score 0):

I can get the following code to work on my system, starting in a directory where sister directory `../output` exists (I don't have `open` on my system so I used `gedit` as the external command):

```
fn <- "HLA-A,B,C,DR,DP,DQ GT2 vs LT2_DRB1_output2of9.10.11.12.13.14.16.25.26.28.30.31.32.33.37.38.40.47.57.58.60.67.70.71.73.74.77.78.85.86.txt"
prot <- function(x) paste0('"',x,'"')
writeLines(c("a","b"),con=paste0("../output/",fn))
n <- tools::file_path_as_absolute(paste0("../output/",fn))
file.show(n)
system2("gedit",prot(n))
```

Can you make a reproducible example along these lines that fails on your system?  (Does `file.show()` work for you?)

(Posting as an answer rather than a comment for purposes of code formatting ...)

Comment: I implemented your code and I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Meaning you've run the code I'm showing above (but with `open` instead of `gedit`)?  Or are you trying to incorporate my ideas into your code? It's conceivable that this is a platform-specific thing (are you on MacOS?), I may be able to try this on a Mac tomorrow -- but otherwise, I can't proceed any further without a **reproducible example** (sorry).  See the link in the comments above ...